# Why is the output value disappearing?

Tags: c, avl-tree

I'm making a program to produce AVL TREE. Typing errors in the past days were solved with help. But the problem remains. I want to make a program that inputs numbers one by one, produces them according to the structure of the AVL tree, and outputs them as a Preorder. However, when outputting, the whole root is not displayed, but only a part of the root is truncated. It seems that information disappears in the process of rotation to produce AVL TREE.
How can we solve this?

And the original intention was to operate the switch statement from the beginning, and to make it work even if you use only insert from the beginning without the process of putting a number in the newnode in the code below. However, if I do that, an error occurs and I have created a process to insert a newnode separately. If you can solve this, how can you do it?

Most of the code was referenced from the Internet and modified as I intended. There are a lot of inexperienced parts, and there is no one to ask, so I ask a question. Thank you very much for your reply.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
    int height;
};

int max(int a, int b);

int height(struct node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    return node->height;
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

struct node *newNode(int item)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = item;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->height = 1;
    return temp;
}

struct node *RRotate(struct node *y)
{
    struct node *x = y->left;
    struct node *T2 = x->right;

    x->right = y;
    y->left = T2;

    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;
    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;

    return x;
}

struct node *LRotate(struct node *x)
{
    struct node *y = x->right;
    struct node *T2 = y->left;

    y->left = x;
    x->right = T2;

    x->height = max(height(x->left), height(x->right)) + 1;
    y->height = max(height(y->left), height(y->right)) + 1;

    return y;
}

int makeBalance(struct node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(node->left) - height(node->right);
}

struct node *insert(struct node *root, int data)
{

    if (root == NULL)
        return newNode(data);

    if (data < root->data)
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    else
        return root;

    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    int balance = makeBalance(root);

    if (balance < -1 && data > root->right->data)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Left Rotation");
        return LRotate(root);
    }
    if (balance > 1 && data < root->left->data)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Right Rotation");
        return RRotate(root);

    }
    if (balance > 1 && data > root->left->data)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Left Rotation\n");
        printf("Right Rotation");
        root->left = LRotate(root->left);
        return RRotate(root);
    }
    if (balance < -1 && data < root->right->data)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Right Rotation\n");
        printf("Left Rotation");
        root->right = RRotate(root->right);
        return LRotate(root);
    }

    return root;
}

struct node *minV(struct node *root)
{
    struct node *current = root;

    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}

struct node *deleteN(struct node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return root;
    if (data < root->data)
        root->left = deleteN(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = deleteN(root->right, data);
    else
    {
        if ((root->left == NULL) || (root->right == NULL))
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;

            if (temp == NULL)
            {
                temp = root;
                root = NULL;
            }
            else
                *root = *temp;
            free(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *temp = minV(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = deleteN(root->right, temp->data);
        }
    }

    if (root==NULL)
        return root;

    root->height = 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));

    int balance = makeBalance(root);
    if (balance > 1 && makeBalance(root->left) >= 0)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Right Rotation");
        return RRotate(root);
    }
    if (balance > 1 && makeBalance(root->left) < 0)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Left Rotation\n");
        printf("Right Rotation");
        root->left = LRotate(root->left);
        return RRotate(root);
    }
    if (balance < -1 && makeBalance(root->right) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Left Rotation");
        return LRotate(root);
    }

    if (balance < -1 && makeBalance(root->right) > 0)
    {
        printf("Node %d Balance Factor is %d\n", root->data, balance);
        printf("Right Rotation\n");
        printf("Left Rotation");
        root->right = RRotate(root->right);
        return LRotate(root);
    }

    return root;
}

struct node *search(struct node *root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not Found Number %d", data);
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (data == root->data)
    {
        printf("Found Number %d", data);
        return root;
    }
    else if (data < root->data)
    {
        return search(root->left, data);
    }
    else
    {
        return search(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
}

void preorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d-", root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    int number;
    int number2;
    int number3;
    bool bOnLoop = true;
    printf("Insert root number:");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    root = newNode(number);
    while (bOnLoop)
    {
        printf("\n1.Insert 2.Delete 3.Search 4.Preorder 5.End\n");
        printf("Select Mode Number:");
        scanf("%d", &number3);
        switch (number3)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            insert(root, number2);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            deleteN(root, number2);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Insert Number:");
            scanf("%d", &number2);
            search(root, number2);
            break;
        case 4:
            preorder(root);
            break;
        case 5:
            bOnLoop = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see a whole lot of code, zero comments, and no steps to reproduce a specific problem.   Start by removing all your UI (comment-out the entire main function and write a fresh one).  Now, create your empty tree and print it.  Test.  Then, hard-code adding a single node (do not prompt).  Print the tree.  Test.  Now, add a second node.  Print the tree. Test.  Try your second node higher or lower.  Continue in this manner until you have found the simplest possible way to break your tree.  Now, in the debugger, step through one line at a time and see what your program is actually doing.

Comment: I took the liberty of doing this and it's clear the simplest case happens as soon as the tree is balanced: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/j9dc8erfh).  The problem is that tree rotations can affect the root, and you're not calling `insert` correctly.  You should do: `root = insert(root, number2);` to ensure your root is always pointing at the correct place: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/aTK3WqjMa)